# What is the brand of this 3D printer?

Tags: desktop-printer, part-identification

Could anyone help me to find out what is the brand name of this 3D printer?

[image: 3D printer]

I found this printer while playing Spider-Man on PS4 in the Lab

[image]

Comment: the fact that it is a digital item was rather crucial: they used a printer. if you could check the files, then it might tell you how the manufacturer refers to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printer on picture looks like LulzBot TAZ.

It could be some prototype or a self-made built or just inspired by it (as it is a digital rendition), because there is no sign of any branding on it. There are [similar builds on Thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2056402).